# What's the best way to do a git clone-or-update?

Tags: git

If I have a suite of git repositories (that aren't otherwise associated with a submodule, subtree etc.) that I want to clone to do data analytics on, I can run something like:

```
for u in $urls; do git clone $url; done
```

However, if the repositories are already checked out in that location, I would need instead to update them and/or reset them to what the result of a clone would be (e.g. a clean slate, no changes):

```
for r in $repos; do git -C $r fetch origin; git -C $r reset --hard origin/HEAD; git -C $r clean -fxd; done
```

Is there a cleaner way to do an effective clone-but-overwrite option in fewer or cleaner steps?

Comment: maybe run `git clone "$url"||git -C "$r" pull` if you never modify the repositories.

Comment: I'd prefer to check the other way around: `git -C "$r" pull || git clone "$url"`